# Angularjs ui-select: how to set selected value for multiple dropdowns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I have multiple ui-selects on the page. How can I set selected value for each of the item separately, thus using single list retrieved from service?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <ui-select class="col-sm-12 no-padding" ng-model="mappingStrengthList.selected">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose strength">
   <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (mappingStrengthList | filter: $select.search) track by item.id">
   <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
   </ui-select-choices>
   </ui-select>
 </div> 
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <ui-select class="col-sm-12 no-padding" ng-model="mappingStrengthList.selected">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose strength">
   <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (mappingStrengthList | filter: $select.search) track by item.id">
   <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
   </ui-select-choices>
   </ui-select>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
ListService.getList('mapping-strength').then(function (results) {
                $scope.mappingStrengthList = results;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want differents selected value, your model should be different, right now you use : `ng-model="mappingStrengthList.selected"` on both.

I don't think you should even use `mappingStrengthList` it's the data that will populate the option, the model should be something else.

Comment: I have dynamically populated list of dropdowns, can I create models dynamically?

Comment: No, what I mean is, you need to have different model for each one, the value of the model will be the value of the selected option, you should do something like `ng-model="myModel"` and `ng-model="myModel2"`. and in your controller : `$scope.myModel` and `$scope.myModel2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.mappingStrengthList.selected = 'YOUR-VALUE-WHICH-YOU-WANT-SET'
```

Comment: Yah that is make sense you have to make each model for each selectbox that is only way